# Как правильно сравнить две таблицы в базе по структуре и внести изменения

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Задача такая, по логике моего приложения, (оно уже работает), нужно подключиться к базе и проверить, соответствует ли таблицы в базе, к которой я подключаюсь, той структуре базы данных, которая содержится в моем приложении, и если таблица не соответствует то изменить ее. Логически задача простая, но база у меня Oracle, и так как я новичок, то  чтобы избежать потери времени хочу узнать, как лучше делать такое сравнение. Есть у меня TOAD (лягушка), и в ней есть механизм сравнения структур таблиц, казалось бы бери структуру и сравнивай, но вопрос в том, как алгоритмически построить правильно функцию для сравнения, которую я затем встрою в свое приложение, может есть какие то уже готовые решения именно для Оракла. Также отмечу, что  нужна сохранность данных. Данные не должны теряться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вижу несколько вариантов:
**1. Пересоздание таблицы**:
Проверяем, есть ли таблица с таким именем:

```
SELECT t.table_name       
FROM   dba_tables t       
WHERE  t.owner = 'your_owner' 
and    t.table_name = 'your_table' 
ORDER  BY t.table_name;
```

Если есть делаем `drop table ...`  и `create table ...`.
Это всегда будет приводить к потере данных. Но любые другие пути будут значительно сложнее, так как универсальная модификация таблицы с поддержкой консистентности может быть нетривиальной задачей. Чаще всего это самый простой и эффективный путь. Важно помнить, что при `drop table` так же могут быть дропнуты все внешние ключи на эту таблицу.

**2. Сравнивать версии таблицы:**
Для промышленной эксплуатации чаще всего не допустимо делать все время `drop\create`. Мы создавали отдельную таблицу, которая хранила версии нашего продукта. В патчах установки был прописан алгоритм поведения в зависимости от версии. 
В результате в наших исходника таблица создавалась только первый раз, а все остальные накаты содержали скрипты модификации исходной таблицы

**3. Если очень хочется универсально анализировать изменения таблицы:**
3.1 Есть различные продукты для выполнения похожих задач, например  от [RED GATE](https://www.red-gate.com/products/).
3.2 Если очень хочется самому, можно получить скрипт создания таблицы из системного словаря
3.2.1 из таблиц в БД.
Можно писать свои запросы из `dba_tables`, `dba_columns`, `dba_tab_cols` и других
Некоторые скрипты для этого можно найти [тут](https://oracle-base.com/dba/scripts), например скрипт `table_defs.sql` покажет часть определения таблицы:

```
SELECT table_name,
       column_id,
       column_name,
       data_type,
       (CASE
         WHEN data_type IN ('VARCHAR2','CHAR') THEN TO_CHAR(data_length)
         WHEN data_scale IS NULL OR data_scale = 0 THEN TO_CHAR(data_precision)
         ELSE TO_CHAR(data_precision) || ',' || TO_CHAR(data_scale)
       END) "SIZE",
       DECODE(nullable, 'Y', '', 'NOT NULL') nullable
FROM   user_tab_columns
WHERE  table_name = DECODE(UPPER('&1'), 'ALL', table_name, UPPER('&1'))
ORDER  BY table_name, column_id;
```

Этот запрос захватывает далеко не все из определения таблицы. Но он указывает направление поиска.  Отдельно надо будет поискать индексы, constraint'ы, выданные на таблицу привилегии и возможно что-то еще
3.2.2 Использовать пакет [DBMS_METADATA](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#ARPLS026) для получения исходников. Например для начала:

```
DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME') from dual
```

**UPD на основе комментариев**
Вы хотите при старте приложения каждый раз проверять структуру БД и обновлять ее при необходимости. Такой подход обязательно приведет к проблемам, это просто вопрос времени. Однажды у вас окажется, что после обновления приложения версия БД новее вашего приложения. И вы испортите ваши данные. Это обязательно случится, кто-то случайно накатит не ту версию или просто подключится более старой версией приложения. В общем это вопрос не если, а когда.

Рассмотрите разделение установки и ежедневной эксплуатации и введите версионность приложения и структуры БД.
Таким образом вы получите ряд дополнительных возможностей:
1. И БД и приложение будут обновляться одновременно.
2. Вы сможете проверять совместимость версии приложения с версией БД и не запускать в ситуациях, когда нет полной совместимости.
3. Среду разработки можно восстанавливать из бэкапа прома(при необходимости обезличивая). Дальше вы просто обновляете БД до разрабатываемой версии приложения.
4. Вы частично обезопаситесь от ошибок людей разворачивающих ваше приложение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, очень интересно , меня как раз вопрос мучает с потерей данных, я не должен терять данные, а изменения мои это чаще всего изменения первичного ключа, внешнего ключа плюс сиквенсы, грубо говоря есть таблица, в ней нужно изменить первичный ключ, внешний ключ, если нужно и добавить новое поле типа OID вместе с сиквенсом к этому полю.

Comment: Присмотритесь к пути номер 2. Пускай у вас будет всегда после создания дальше будет выполнятся `alter table add column ..` и тому подобное

Comment: Ок посмотрю . но в моем случае таблице в базе не имеют версионности. Да я думаю про Alter table. Но вопрос как сравнить с эталоном.

Comment: Это более общая задача о том, как вообще организовывать `dev` контур и следить за актуальностью таблиц

Comment: То есть версию надо держать скорее не таблицы, а всего ядра или продукта. Чтобы таблицам соответствовал и ваш код на c#.  Теперь у меня складывается, что вы хотите при каждом старте приложения проверять структуру таблиц. Если это так, то просто разделите работу с приложением на 2 части: 1 - это непосредственно установка и обновление вашего приложения. 2 - ежедневная работа.

Comment: Да  мне нужно каждый раз при старте приложения проверять верна ли структура таблицы, если нет делать ее замену.

Comment: Мне кажется, что у вас с архитектурой приложения что-то не так. Так вы обязательно выстрелите себе в ногу. Подумайте над отдельной установкой приложения и его повседневной работой. У такого подхода ряд плюсов: 0. И бд и приложения накатываются одновременно 1. Вы сможете создать отдельного пользователя для наката и разграничить права. 2. Вы сможете вести версии ваших дистрибутивов(я прям настаиваю, что это надо делать) 3. Вы сможете организовать среды разработки просто бэкапами с прома(с возможной обезличкой) и просто донакатывать на них  нужную версию дистрибутива.

Comment: Иначе вы обязательно столкнетесь с ситуацией, когда у вас в БД будет одна версия, в приложении другая. И если вам не повезет, то более старая версия приложения начнет уничтожать вашу БД. Восстанавливать данные после этого будет тяжело, а если нет качественных бэкапов то может быть вообще не возможно

Comment: Да я буду вводить версионность в базе, путем создания доп. таблицы. Но вопрос технически как мне проводить сравнение, как это организовать. То есть смотрим, какая версия базы, исходя из этой версией накатываем изменения, или я как то не так понял, ибо данные уже есть в таблице и нужно сделать так,чтобы данные не потерялись.

Comment: Именно так. При накате обновления вы обновляете вашу версию в  таблице БД.

Comment: А как саму проверку организовать? Я имею ввиду вот есть таблица A и таблица Эталон. Мне же нужно  проверить совпадает по структуре эти две таблицы или нет, и если нет, тогда делаю накат(выполняю скрипт). Изменю версию базы данных в таблице специальной, и далее если версия есть, то ориентируюсь на нее, а если версии нет (много баз придется идентичных проверить), тогда также сверяю таблицы , создаю таблицу версионности. Правильно ли я вас понял?

Comment: Можно и так. Если у вас на всех базах сейчас структура одинаковая, то просто сделайте скрипт который донакатит до новой. Если полный бардак, то придется потратить некоторое время и выделить то, в чем они разделяются и это накатить. Например проверять, есть ли колонка. И если нет, то добавлять. А дальше уже версии и никакого бардака

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch У меня в одной системе было сделано так; в специальной таблице лежали: код объекта (заказчика) на котором развернута БД, глобальный номер версии, локальный номер версии. И был отдельный "патчер", фактически исполнитель sql запросов. Кроме собственно прогона sql он понимал несколько команд, `!0001` устанавливал версию, причем если текущий номер версии в БД больше, то блок пропускался до следующего `!`. При успешном выполнении блока номер версии в БД менялся. И примерно то же но с проверкой "кода объекта" и "локальной версии" (только для данного объекта)

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Это позволяло засылать не объекты SQL файлы не думая о том, что там уже ранее прогонялось а что нет. И главное, в общем потоке патчей можно написать SQL который должен быть выполнен только у одного заказчика. Так как работа систем была критически важной то перед отправкой на объект мы прогоняли у себя на копии клиентской БД все патчи и убеждались что ничего не сломается

Comment: @Mike Спасибо за ценную информацию я примерно так и обдумываю вариант решения.